# objects not added to arraylist (asynctask)

Tags: android

In my main activity I got an arraylist called data. I call an asynctask and do some stuff that gives me a different arraylist called values.

In the post execute of the asynctask I want to use items in 'values' to add some objects to 'data'. However, when debugging I noticed that the objects dont get added.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    ArrayList<DataItem> data;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = new ArrayList<DataItem>();
    update();


}

public void update()
{

    AsyncCallAWS thisTask = new AsyncCallAWS();
    thisTask.execute(); 
}

private class AsyncCallAWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{   
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(); 

   protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        DataItem d;
        for(String s : values)
        {
            d = new DataItem();
            d.setValue(s);
            d.setDataStreamName("test");
            data.add(d);        
        }

    }

//code to fill array
```

I'm guessing it's because I try to add items from the asynctask? Idk how to solve this, I need the data arraylist for a listview.

Comment: are you sure there is anything at all in values ?

Comment: define 'don't get added'

Comment: add some logging before and after to output your items to ensure they are actually holding the values that you think they are. Also you are probably going to have to share a bit more of your code. To address your fears though, no simply having your add statements inside of an AsyncTask will not cause them not to get added.

Comment: Yes values has 6 objects. 'dont get added' as in data is still empty after the onPostExecute.

Comment: Please, help everyone.  Learn how to use the debugger.  It's simple, takes 30 minutes to learn and you'll never have to ask a question like this again.  You would put a breakpoint on `for(String s : values)`, inspect `values` and find that it does not contain what you think it does.  I can see just by looking at the code that it will always be empty, therefore your for loop doesn't execute therefore `data` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AsyncTask class override method `onProgressUpdate()`, where you will add elements to array. Then in `doInBackground()` call `publishProgress()` for sending elements to `onProgressUpdate()`. Here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html -is great example.

```
private class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object> {

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String item = "";

    //Do some stuff

    publishProgress(item);

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(String... value) {
    data.add(value[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should create objects in the onPostExecute-method. Instead create it in the doInBackground-method of the class that extends AsyncTask, and then use set-methods in the onPostExecute-metod.